# Dynamically fork Beam (Dataflow) Pipeline Based on number of TaggedOutputs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm currently attempting to fork a Beam pipeline running on Google Dataflow into many destinations based on a specific key contained within the data. I am able to get this working when hardcoding each of the endpoints of the 'fork' with the TaggedOutput tag. However, in the future, I will not always know what keys exist in the underlying data, so I am looking to dynamically create the subsequent steps in the process using a for loop similar to the below:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

pipe = p | 'ReadFromGCS' >> ReadFromText(args['input']) \
         | 'TagAllLines' >> beam.ParDo(produce_tagged_output_keys).with_outputs()

for client in pipe:
  client = pipe.client | client+'MapLinesToDicts' >> beam.Map(lambda line: dict(record=line)) \
                         | client+'WriteToBQTable' >> WriteToBigQuery(client+'_test', dataset=bq_dataset, project=project_id, schema='record:string')
```

My understanding is that the results of  `.with_outputs()` should be iterable, no? When I run the above, it executes `pipe` without issue, but ignores the for loop entirely. Is there a way to dynamically do this that I am missing?

Comment: This is supported in Beam Java for writing to files and to BigQuery. Is it an option for you to switch to Beam Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The result of `.with_outputs()` is only iterable if tags are specified**

The result of `.with_outputs()` without specifying tags is not iterable, since the outputs are not yet known at pipeline construction time.
The result of `.with_outputs(tag1, tag2, main=tag0)` however is iterable:
[Test the difference here](https://gist.github.com/RobbeSneyders/9b2b76237728e640ec497d70bae4a8ad)

Remember that with apache beam, you first construct the pipeline, and then let the data flow through it. So you can't let your pipeline architecture depend on the data at runtime.

**I'll propose another solution however:**

Let's assume you have a `pcollection` *collection* with elements structured like this:

```
(key, bq_row)
```

Where the *key* is the feature deciding which table to write to and *bq_row* the data you want to write to a bigquery row.

You can then group the elements by key:

```
grouped = collection | beam.GroupByKey()
```

Now you get one element for every different key. So all the *bq_row*'s in one element should be written to the same bigquery table, which depends on the element key.

You can then define a `DoFn` which writes all the rows in each element to the appropriate table. (example code)

```
class WriteToBigQueryFn(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self, dataset_name):
        super(BigQueryWriter, self).__init__()
        self.client = bigquery.Client()
        self.dataset = client.dataset(dataset_name)

    def process(self, (key, data)):
        table_name = get_table_name(key) # get table name based on key
        table = self.dataset.table(table_name)
        table.reload(self.client)

        table.insert_data(data)

grouped | beam.ParDo(WriteToBigQueryFn)
```

Comment: My understanding, per the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs) is that the results of `.with_outputs()` is iterable; but regardless, I'll give your suggestion a try!

Comment: The result of `.with_outputs()` is only iterable if the tags are specified. I've added some clarification with a code example to my answer.

Comment: @andre622 `with_outputs()` returns a `DoOutputsTuple` which is an iterable type, but without tags the `DoOutputsTuple`only contains the main output, so technically an iterable of 1.

Comment: I take it back, the class implements `__iter__()` which is arguably enough to call it an iterable, however it doesn't yield i.e. it's an iterable of 0 if you don't supply either `tag` args or the `main` keyword arg see https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fb4b151135451192d4e7c74d8eecdc9f35d21a42/sdks/python/apache_beam/pvalue.py#L211